# Matlab : Confusion over find() function

Tags: arrays, matlab

`find()` function returns the indices where the elements are non-zero. I tried with different array sizes but both give error :

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
```

I am confused because when the array size is same, still I am getting this error.

This is just to understand what went wrong:
LEt,

Example 1: Same array size

```
A = [20;21;3;45;5;19;1;8;2;1];
B = A;
 for i =1:length(B)
pos(i) = find(A == B(i));
end
```

I should have got `pos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. But the loops exits after `i = 7`, giving `pos = [1,2,3,4,5,6]'

Example 2: Dissimilar array size

```
 C = [20;1;10;3];

 for i =1:length(C)
    pos(i) = find(A == C(i));
    end
```

Can somebody please explain what is wrong in my understanding and an illustration of how I can work with same and different array length of A and B? Thank you.

Comment: Read the error: the problem is with the assignment. `find()` returns you an array, and you *assign* it to a scalar, `pos(i)`. Unless there's a single element for which `A==B(i)` is true, you're bound to have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that find(A == 1) returns two indexes, both 7 and 10, and that can't be stored in pos(i), since pos(i) can only hold a single number.

Unfortunately, the generic error message happened to have the same name for the matrices as two of your matrices, which can be confusing before you'we seen it a few times.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As far as my understanding goes, this error can appear when the same element appears in different index position in an array (e.q;  when each of the array contains all unique elements say A = [20;21;3;45;5;19;1;8;2;15]; then there is no error). Moreover, I can now work with different sized arrays provided the condition that each array contains unique elements. Is there a way to prevent such an error because in many cases, I will not have any control over the elements of the arrays; yet I need to apply find().